# java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD' for column 'name' at row 1

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I had the same project with spring6 and it didn't give me any problems, now with spring 5 if I try to insert the name of an author that contains a special character e.g. (Niccolò) I get this error

```
2023-09-15 11:01:50.754  WARN 28709 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
2023-09-15 11:01:50.754 ERROR 28709 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD' for column 'name' at row 1
2023-09-15 11:01:50.767 ERROR 28709 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/addAuthors] due to exception [could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement]
```

This is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.15</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bookshelf2</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
#MySQL8Dialect
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

This is the method and print this "Niccol�"

```
@PostMapping("addAuthors")
public String addauthors(@ModelAttribute ("addAuthor") Author author){
    String name = author.getName();
    
    System.out.println(name);

    authorService.save(author);
    return "redirect:addAuthors";
}
```

I tried to fix with this but for the input "Niccolò" the output is "Niccol?"

```
@PostMapping("addAuthors")
public String addauthors(@ModelAttribute ("addAuthor") Author author){
    String name = author.getName();

    byte[] bytes = name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    name = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(name);
    author.setName(name);

    authorService.save(author);
    return "redirect:addAuthors";
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same JDK and deserializer (gson) as your previous project?

Comment: @dcolazin yes all the same